# It inserts multiple data instead of one only

Tags: c#

I am using SQL Server 2014 and my problem is, when I click the Save Button to save a Salary data, it gives multiple data instead of one data only and this is my code:

```
   private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.dataGet("Select * from EmpAttendance Where Year = '" + 
  cmbYear.Text + "' and Month = '" + cmbMonth.Text + "'");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.sda.Fill(dt);


        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                con.dataGet(@"SELECT ES.Salary, EA.WorkingDays,                  
     EA.Presentdays, EA.LopDays FROM EmpAttendance EA INNER JOIN 
     EmpSalary ES ON EA.EmpId = ES.EmpId
                        Where EA.Year = '"+ cmbYear.Text +"' and EA.Month 
     = '"+ cmbMonth.Text +"' and EA.EmpId = '"+ dt.Rows[0] 
     ["EmpId"].ToString() +"'");


                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                con.sda.Fill(dt1);


                salary = float.Parse(dt1.Rows[0]["Salary"].ToString());
                workingDays = float.Parse(dt1.Rows[0]["WorkingDays"].ToString());
                present = float.Parse(dt1.Rows[0]["PresentDays"].ToString());
                lop = float.Parse(dt1.Rows[0]["LopDays"].ToString());
                perDay = (salary / 12) / workingDays;
                netSalary = (perDay * present) - (perDay * lop);


                con.dataSend("INSERT INTO SalaryProcess (EmpId, Year, 
      Month, NetSalary) VALUES ('" + dt.Rows[0]["EmpId"].ToString() + "', 
      '" + cmbYear.Text + "', '" + cmbMonth.Text + "', '" + netSalary + 
      "')");


                MessageBox.Show("Salary Generated!", "Message", 
      MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                LoadData();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Parameterize your SQL queries. Why do you think it should insert a single row? Does the first select return a single row?

Comment: so what do you want to do now ? do you want to insert multiple data into the database ?

Comment: Some things that can bite you: **Problem 1**: you use string concatenation instead of parameters (look up on "SQL injection"), **problem 2**: you use strings for what appear to be numerical columns.

Comment: Where exactly do you get that "multiple data"? Could you explain that as an [edit] to your question? Note that you never appear to check whether there is already a row in that SalaryProcess for this employee and month

Comment: 1. Debug if code loops twice
2. Print out your generated SQL queries(string) and run against db using management studio

Comment: It should insert single row only but it inserts multiple rows

Comment: Yeah, you said that already... why do you expect it to insert a single row? Your code as it stands will insert a row for each entry returned by the first query (because you're looping through those records).

Comment: How can I remove it? so that I can only see single row?

Comment: Which row do you want it to see? The facts: The first query returns multiple rows. Your code is loops through them.

Comment: Add **Break;** or **return**; at the end of foreach

Comment: @DevC Or, just don't use `foreach`. That leads us to the problem I'm trying to get an answer to: if the first query returns multiple rows, which is one is correct?

Comment: @John He always uses index 0 **dt1.Rows[0]** but yeah why using foreach when he never uses **DataRow row** You'r right

Comment: Base your loop on the 2nd select query where you join attendance with the emp table, problem will be solved.... And take care of parameter etc as mentioned above

Comment: SOLVED! GUYS! THANKS! :D